# Why don't my buttons work after I add padding to the container?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, bootstrap-4

I am having issues making my buttons appear active. Currently, they don't actually do anything, but they don't even appear to be active with a hover effect. I have tried adding effects to them, but nothing seems to change when I do this.

I have tried removing all different parts of the css, and when padding is removed from the container, the buttons become active again, but this only happens sometimes?

I am unsure what I am doing wrong, I am obviously a complete n00b at this, as this is my first real attempt in making an actual website, and have only played around with html/css for fun.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, thank you so much!

```css
.container {
  padding: 10%;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFEA9F;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
 border: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 background:linear-gradient(to right,#FFE899,#F48C30);
}

.bottom {
 position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}


#mainNav {
  font-weight: 100;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  color: #FFEA9F;
}

#mainNav .nav-link {
  color: #FFEA9F;
}

#mainNav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #F48C30;
}

.collapse {
  color: #FFEA9F;
}

.button {
  background-color: #8C1909; 
  border: none;
  color: #FFEA9F;
  /*padding: 10px 25px;*/
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #544D4D;
  grid-row-start:1;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #8C1909; 
  border: none;
  color: #FFEA9F;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #544D4D;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testing2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Code|Red+Hat+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<body>
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: #8C1909">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">HOME</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="https://google.com/maps" class="nav-link">MAPS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="https://instagram.com/venture.mars" class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

<div class="container">
 <h1 class="text-center">VENTURE.MARS</h1>
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center flex-column flex-md-row" style="height: 200px">
  <button class="button" type="submit">CREATE</button>
  <button class="button2" type="submit">EXPLORE</button>
 </div>

</div>


<div class="bottom">
 <img src="background_bottom2.svg">
</div>
</body>
```

I would like the buttons to remain active regardless of padding.

I would appreciate feedback on other issues you may see, anything helps! A couple years back I was taught Java by an amazing instructor who always enforced making our code as practical as possible, without using work-arounds. Although I feel I have been creating a lot of work-arounds trying to figure out html/css on my own.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "active". If we are talking the "Create" and "Explore" buttons, the are active as indicated by the cursor changing when hovering over them. "I have tried adding effects to them" - please show what you have tried here.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the entire code with more organization and it seems to be working. Only problem I ran into was not being able to add a background color with an img on top, so I just used an img instead. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When using bootstrap, `navbar-brand` should only be used for the brand (the site name). You shouldn't be using it for every navbar element. You should be using `.nav-item nav-link` for linked navbar items.

curious as to why you're formatting it not as a `ul` element with `li` list items for your navigation? EDIT: Should mention that it isn't required, but it is pretty standard.

Revisit the documentation for navbars, because it will definitely help. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#brand

Also, you may want to style this using an ID for specificity, and also use the pseudoselectors a:active a:visited to make sure your color remains the same after the link is visited or is active.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for responding. I was able to fix the issue by removing "navbar-dark" but using nav-item nav-link removes my custom colors. Also, a:link, a:visited and etc does not work in my css, even if I update to nav-item nav-link. I am considering rewriting my entire code because it's kind of all over the place atm. My buttons still don't appear to be active, not sure if it will change after adding an actual link, but they work just fine if I remove my .css file, so it has to do with something in how the html and css are communicating, have yet to figure this out.

Comment: I have also updated this post because of making recent changes to my script

Comment: I ended up rewriting the entire code with more organization and it seems to be working. Only problem I ran into was not being able to add a background color with an img on top, so I just used an img instead. Thank you everyone for your help!